# Why must the number type be declared in printf (when used with putStr) for a script but not for ghci?

Tags: haskell, types, printf, ghci

Why is the `3` ambiguous in `putStr (printf "abc%d\n" 3)` when running as a script but then **not** ambiguous when running in ghci? That is, why must I declare the type of `3` in the script but not ghci?

Here is operation within `ghci`:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> putStr "abc3\n"
abc3
Prelude> import Text.Printf
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "abc%d\n" 3
abc3
Prelude Text.Printf> let main = putStr (printf "abc%d\n" 3)
Prelude Text.Printf> main
abc3
Prelude Text.Printf> let main = printf "abc%d\n" 3 :: String
Prelude Text.Printf> main
"abc3\n"
Prelude Text.Printf> :quit
Leaving GHCi.
```

Here is correct operation of the `script` when declaring as `Int`:

```
$ cat runmain-good
#!/usr/bin/env runghc
import Text.Printf
main = putStr (printf "abc%d\n" (3 :: Int))
$ ./runmain-good
abc3
```

Here is erroneous operation of the `script` with when the type of `3` is ambiguous ... with the typical user-friendly Haskell error:

```
$ cat runmain-bad
#!/usr/bin/env runghc
import Text.Printf
main = putStr (printf "abc%d\n" 3)
$ ./runmain-bad

runmain-bad:3:16:
    No instance for (PrintfArg a0) arising from a use of `printf'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance [safe] PrintfArg Char -- Defined in `Text.Printf'
      instance [safe] PrintfArg Double -- Defined in `Text.Printf'
      instance [safe] PrintfArg Float -- Defined in `Text.Printf'
      ...plus 12 others
    In the first argument of `putStr', namely `(printf "abc%d" 3)'
    In the expression: putStr (printf "abc%d" 3)
    In an equation for `main': main = putStr (printf "abc%d" 3)

runmain-bad:3:33:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `3'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus 11 others
    In the second argument of `printf', namely `3'
    In the first argument of `putStr', namely `(printf "abc%d" 3)'
    In the expression: putStr (printf "abc%d" 3)
```

Comment: You know the putStr is not needed?

Comment: Thank @augustss. I did not realize this. I just tried out your tip. Of course, dropping the `putStr` doesn't remove the _literal 3 ambiguous_ error. But now the correct expression reduces to just `main = printf "abc%d\n" (3 :: Int)`. ... The mathematical succinctness of Haskell is one of its most beautiful features because it helps to illuminate the essence of an algorithm, especially with the strong use of Hindley-Milner although the number can't be disambiguated in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHCi simply has relaxed defaulting rules enabled by default (so that literal `5` defaults to `Integer`), just to make your life easier.

You can achieve a similar effect in GHC by enabling `ExtendedDefaultRules`.

See [GCHi docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) for a more elaborate discussion of this.